# Retrofit need JsonReader.setLenient(true)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.0 beta4, i want to json from url

-) My interface

```
interface UserWebService {
    @GET("JsonViewUsers.aspx")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

-) My retrofit object

```
protected Retrofit getRestAdapter() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://ganah.zagel1.com/Pages/JsonData/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

-) My code

```
getUsers().enqueue(new RequestCallback<List<User>>(this) {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            Log.w("Result", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w("Result", t.getMessage());
        }
});
```

-) Log result : Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 3 column 1 path $

how can i solve this problem ?